How to remove x on lightning pill but in LWC
I saw there is an answer to this question but its not working for LWC, I think it does the job for aura component, so what do I need to write in Css so I can have x removed from all my lightning pills?
Thanks.

AFAIK you can't with the standard lightning-pill. But you could create your own very simple LWC that leaves out the "x" button using the HTML from the Pills SLDS documentation.


Create a static resource in which create a css file having the below css.
   .emptyClass .slds-pill__remove{
    display:none !important;
}

Import that in your lwc cmp.
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import MY_RESOURCE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myResource';

export default class Pillwithoutcross extends LightningElement {
     connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, MY_RESOURCE )
            .then(() => {
                // Styles are loaded
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle error
            });
    }

}

<template>
    <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Pill without remove Icon" >
        <p>With using additional class emptyClass</p>
        <lightning-pill label="With emptyClass" class="emptyClass">
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" alternative-text="Account"></lightning-icon>
    </lightning-pill>
    <p>Without using additional class emptyClass</p>
        <lightning-pill label="Without emptyClass" >
        <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:account" alternative-text="Account"></lightning-icon>
    </lightning-pill>
    </lightning-card>
 
</template>

The x icon will dissaper.

Does the style have to be loaded from a StaticResource?  Would the .css file that is part of the component work?

yes u need to load from static resource and no, the .css file that is part of the component would not work.
